# What library can I use to work with directed weighted graphs in Go?

Tags: go

As per title, I need to work with directed weighted graphs. I thought I could use Go instead of Python since I heard it's blazing fast but I'm really having a harder time than I thought.

I couldn't find a proper library for working with graphs and coming from PHP and Python I was astonished by the nearly complete absence of adequate documentation for Go in general.

These are the libraries that I found and the problem I encountered:

| Library | Problem |
| --- | --- |
| https://github.com/yourbasic/grapht | Weighted edges work only with int |
| https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dominikbraun/graph | Weighted edges work only with int |
| https://github.com/gonum/gonum | Seems professional but they didn't even bother writing a draft for documentation |

Can you guys help me figure this out?

Comment: https://github.com/yourbasic/grapht seems not to exist anymore?